# Select csv files urls from soup object

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Please, how can I select csv files urls from [soccer historical data](https://www.football-data.co.uk/englandm.php), and save them with name: "state" + "season" + "name of csv file"? Im lost in this field...

```
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver2.get("https://www.football-data.co.uk/englandm.php")
pgsource2 = driver2.page_source
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(pgsource2, 'html.parser')

x = soup2.find_all('table')

for a in x.find_all('a', href=True):
        y = a['href']
        print(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can find all `.csv` files and save them locally:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.football-data.co.uk/"
page = requests.get(urljoin(base_url, "englandm.php")).text
anchors = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").find_all(
    lambda t: t.name == "a" and ".csv" in t["href"],
)
csv_links = [urljoin(base_url, a["href"]) for a in anchors]

name_mapping = {
    "E0.csv": "Premier_League",
    "E1.csv": "Championship",
    "E2.csv": "League_1",
    "E3.csv": "League_2",
    "EC.csv": "Conference",
}

for csv_link in csv_links:
    *_, date, file_name = csv_link.split("/")
    print(f"Fetching {csv_link}...")
    with open(f"{'_'.join([date, name_mapping[file_name]])}.csv", "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(csv_link).content)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my version

```
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser')
    main_table = soup2.find('a', href=re.compile(r'.csv')).parent
    result = {}
    curent_key = 'none'
    for item in main_table:
        if item.name == 'i':
            curent_key = item.text
            print(curent_key)
            if not curent_key in result:
                result[curent_key] = []
            else: continue
        if item.name == 'a' and item['href'] and curent_key in result:
            result[curent_key].append({ 'href': item['href'], 'text': item.text })
        
    print(result)
```